# Read a single char from stdin without pressing enter

Tags: crystal-lang

How can I read a single char from the console without pressing enter / return?

In ruby I would just use:

```
require 'io/console'
input = STDIN.getch
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
char = STDIN.raw &.read_char
p char
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent of `STDIN.ready?` ? When I am reading Meta/Alt characters or Shifted-Fn keys, I keep reading while `STDIN.ready?` and return with the collected keys when it is not ready.

Comment: **NB:** This no longer works in 1.11.1.