# Read whole lines from $stdin without pressing enter with crystal-lang

Tags: crystal-lang

It's a similar question that [Read a single char from stdin without pressing enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39964008/read-a-single-char-from-stdin-without-pressing-enter)

How do I read whole lines with crystal-lang ? I assume to use following Ruby equivalent code:

```
lines = $stdin.read
lines.each{|line| puts line}
```

Comment: How would you send a line to stdin without pressing enter/newline character?

Comment: see this https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/crystal-lang/2y-JTQ6a_7Q/YfwVEpSSGgAJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the equivalent of `read` is `STDIN.gets_to_end` FWIW.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/crystal-lang/O4DExFHJc5E

Comment: @rogerpack Thanks, it's the most ideal answer. I should have asked for the forum.

Answer (score 2):

Again, you use `STDIN.raw` but this time you want to fetch a whole line at a time using `IO#gets`. The easiest way to do that is this:

```
while line = STDIN.raw &.gets
  puts line
end
```

Alternatively you could do this:

```
STDIN.raw do |stdin|
  stdin.each_line do |line|
    puts line
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks but, it seems #raw method always requires tty. it's inconvenient for me because I wanted using it for competitive programming

Answer (score 1):

To use this code with online compiler

I just used STDIN directly

```
STDIN.each_line do |line|
  puts line
end
```

Comment: Thanks this avoids a "can't set IO#raw: Inappropriate ioctl for device (Errno)" error message :)